# What does .car stand for in iOS? Compiled Asset (______)..?

Tags: ios

I'm reading this tutorial and I know that your basic asset catalog (Assets.xcassets) in your project gets packaged/bundled and the outcome is an assets.car file. Everywhere I look I see 'compiled assets' but I don't see what the 'r' stands for.

Answer (score 2):

Many file extensions of the form `?ar` are some sort of "archive". Examples include `tar`, `rar`, `ear`, and `jar`. `car` is most likely "compiled asset archive".

Answer (score 1):

Resource... left over from time gone by.